# Xcode: Understanding dependencies with CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swifty-json

Using our release Configuration everything works.  Using a duplicated Configuration we get an error:

> No such module 'SwiftyJSON'

This module is configured through CocoaPods.  Is there something I need to configure when duplicating my Configuration re CocoaPods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to duplicate the Configuration in the same manner in the Pods project as well.  We're in a workspace with two projects - XXX and Pods.  Seems the Configurations need to be in sync between them.